# Inserting header file during compile time

Tags: gcc, qnx, qnx-neutrino, blackberry-qnx

I'm trying to compile a library but some macros are missing. I want to add these macros, which are located in a header file, during compile time. gcc has an `include` option like below:

```
gcc  ...  -include <macros.h> ...
```

How could I achieve this in QNX? I couldn't find an *qcc* option to add header file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case you would like to define a path to the headers file to include, you have to use the `-I` option by defining where the header files are located:

```
qcc ... -I<<path_to_header_files>> ...
```

Otherwise, in case you don't want to insert the `#include` directive in every file that uses the macros defined in a specific header file, you can use the following compiler option:

```
qcc -Wp, -include<<path_to_header_file/file.h>> ...
```

In this way you are telling to the compiler that during the preprocessing phase (`-Wp`) it has to include the header file specified after the `-include` argument.

Comment: But I want to add a specific file. I don't want to add search path for include files.

Comment: @zontragon I see but the *qcc* [page](http://www.qnx.com/developers/docs/6.4.0/neutrino/utilities/q/qcc.html) reports:
    -I path[:path ...]
    Set the search path for #include directives.

Comment: If I use -l, I will have to add macros.h file manually to all cpp files. I just want to add the macros.h file to all cpp files automatically during compile time

Comment: @zontragon Probably the `-W` option described in the previous link can help you. It seems that you can give the `include` option to the prepocessor phase but at the moment I can not test it.

Comment: @zontragon I have the solution for you, I'm going to edit my answer ;)

Comment: @zontragon did the answer help you? It works perfectly for me

Comment: Note: please don't use space!